# Xamarin Live Player .NETStandard 2 Work?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

Does Xamarin Live Player work with .NETStandard2 library?

I have tried with my Android phone as well as an emulator.

The application was out of the box template File - New MasterDetail template.  I have the latest Visual Studio and Live Player.

Error is as follows..

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xamarin.android.support.media.compat/26.1.0.1/lib/MonoAndroid80/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a3c110c11b47c3aa74503830c113c5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xamarin.android.support.media.compat/26.1.0.1/lib/MonoAndroid80/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a3c110c11b47c3aa74503830c113c5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xamarin.android.support.media.compat/26.1.0.1/lib/MonoAndroid80/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a3c110c11b47c3aa74503830c113c5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf
```

> :0 <---
>   <---            1

Comment: Have the dependencies restored successfully? Looks like `Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat` did not.

Comment: Looks like others have the same issue.   
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/116241/live-player-net-standard   The file does exist in this location (build directory) C:\Temp\xamarin\App4\App4\App4.Android\obj\Debug\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll

Comment: Note: Live Player is working fine with IOS/Ipad

Comment: Here is a link to the github sample - https://github.com/dyardyGIT/Xamarin-Sample-App4

Answer (score 0):

An issue was found in the Xamarin Live Player (Android) and a new release was made available within a couple days.